# Double Negative - How to read?

Tags: double-negation

There is no chance the email you recieved isn't a scam.

How to interpret this sentence? If I attempt to remove the double negative, it doesn’t make much sense to me at all.

There is a chance the email you received is a spam? Is this a valid reading of email?

A non-native English speaker here.

Comment: If you remove the double negatives, you get "the email you received is certainly a scam", which is exactly what the sentence means.

Comment: This belongs on English language learner's. The email is spam, there is no chance it isn't. This isn't a "double negative" in common use of the term, it's just two negatives that are close to each other. A double negative would be like, "there ain't no chance..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negatives here do not exactly cancel.  Consider the sentence as a proposition wrapped in a probability.

*There is no chance that X* means that the probability of X is zero, so X is certainly false.

What is certainly false here? That *the email is not a scam*.  If that is certainly false, then the email certainly *is* a scam.

Answer (score 0):

Reworded - There is zero probability, *that* the email you received is not a scam.
The phrase, "no chance" means won't occur, even by accident.
The phrase, "isn't a scam" means is not a scam.
To best analyze writing that contains words that are contractions, I'll almost 
always change those words into the full words.